# Parse Relationship/Merge Tables <Swift>

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a parse database with two classes
1) "Items" with tables "ItemId" and "Shop"
2) "Links" with tables "ItemId" and "Name"

Can I create a relation so I can get the "Shop" for the selected "Name" ?
Or maybe can I merge these two classes ?

I am using Swift and I was thinking something like :

```
var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Items")
query.orderByAscending("Shop")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(results: [PFObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if error == nil && results != nil {
query.whereKey("ItemId", equalTo:results["ItemId"] as! String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a pointer column in parse to connect these 2 classes in order to be able to grab data like that, so that one may have a reference to the other. Note that a pointer column in Class A to class B will give class A a reference to class B, but will not give class B a reference to class A.

for your example here: you create a pointer column in your Links class that points to your Items class. then do something like:

```
// retrieve all objects from Links class
var query = PFQuery(classname: "Links")

// the string for the include key is the name of your pointer column
// this allows you to get items from the class that the pointer column points to
query.includekey("PointerToItemClass")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if error == nil && results != nil {

        for x in results! {

      // this line of code reaches into the Items class and gets 
      // the objects under the "Shop" column
       self.yourStringArray.append(x.objectForKey("PointerToItemClass")!.objectForKey("Shop") as! String)

       }


}
```

to edit again, I should add that yourStringArray is an empty array of strings that you should initialize at the top of your class, like so:

```
 var yourStringArray = [String]()
```

this will allow you a place to store the items you get from the parse database

Comment: So later when I am quering at Class A and get the pfobject , can I have access to the Class B pointer without quering the whole class ?